# what is the difference between tf.nn.convolution and tf.nn.conv2d?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to make dilated convolution on a feature. In tensorflow I found `tf.nn.convolution` and `tf.nn.conv2d`. But `tf.nn.conv2d` doesn't seem to support dilated convolution.

So I tried using `tf.nn.convolution`.

Do the 2 formulations below give the same result?

`tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides=[1, 1, 2, 2], padding='SAME',data_format='NCHW')`

`tf.nn.convolution(x, w, strides=[1, 1, 2, 2], padding='SAME',data_format='NCHW')`

Comment: `tf.nn.conv2d` is from the language agnostic C++ wrapper library that is generated by bazel, `tf.nn.convolution` is from the python specific library. Shouldn't matter which one you use, they both have dilation related arguments.

Comment: @umutto : thank you for your answer. but I can't find the dilation argument in tf.nn.convolution. Maybe it has been updated?

Comment: According to the documentation it is [`dilation_rate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution) argument. Not sure about the versioning on it though.

Comment: @umutto : oh, sorry for my fault. tf.nn.conv2d doesn't have the dilation_rate argument, not tf.nn.convolution. ;p

Comment: No worries, according to the documentation it is [`dilations`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) argument for `tf.nn.conv2d`. Usage seems to differ a bit though.

Answer (score 0):

To use dilated convolution, you need to use the following function:

`tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(value, filters, rate, padding, name=None)`

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn/convolution#atrous_conv2d

Comment: but it is not support the data_format argument, using data_format='NCHW' can speed up. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, `dilations` augument in `tf.nn.conv2d` is the same as `dilations_rate` in `tf.nn.convolution` as well as `rate` in `tf.nn.atrous_conv2d`.

They all represent the rate by which we upsample the filter values by inserting zeros across the height and width dimensions. The dilation factor for each dimension of input specifying the filter upsampling/input downsampling rate otherwise known as atrous convolution.

The usage differs slightly.
Let rate `k >= 1` represent the dilation rate,

- in `tf.nn.conv2d`, the rate `k` is passed as list of ints `[1, k, k,1]` for `[batch, rate_height, rate_width, channel]`.
- in `tf.nn.convolution`, rate `k` is passed as a sequence of `N` ints as `[k,k]` for `[rate_height, rate_width]`.
- in `tf.nn.atrous_conv2d`, rate `k` is a positive `int32`, a single value for both height and width. This library is deprecated and exists only for backwards compatibility.

Hope it helps :)